# Java Libraries specification

Tags: java, specifications

From the preface to the second edition of java language specification:

"*The specifications of the libraries are now far too large to fit into this volume, and
they continue to evolve. Consequently, API specifications have been removed from
this book. The library specifications can be found on the Web;* "

I Was looking for specification of standard library provided as part of Java Programming Language. Any pointer to it? Didn't find it on Oracle.

Comment: If you need any *specific* class, googling for "Java <classname>" works every time.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the API specification for Java 7 here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

For earlier versions:

- Java 6: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/
- Java 5: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/
- Java 1.4.2: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/

And for up-coming Java 8, "subject to change": http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/index.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

from Oracle site

Answer (score 0):

The most current till today in 2018 for **Java 8** *docs* or *API* from *Oracle* site is: [Java™ Platform, Standard Edition 8 API Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/). 
And for **C#** and **.Net** *guides* from Microsoft site which is equivalent to the Java API, the most current version in 2018 is: [C# 6.0 draft Language Specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/),
also [C# Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/) is useful for **C#**.